# Where could one find a 820 & 827 implementation guide and sample data files?

Tags: edi, x12

Im looking for a 820 & 827 implementation guide (ASC X12) standard. (not for a particular company).

Im also looking for a sample data file of each. (this could or could not be for a particular company)

Does anyone know where both of these could be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this site:  http://www.faima.com/edi_4010/tsindex.htm

No sample files, but some nice transaction guidelines.

Comment: I found this site already on my own, but i liked your answer and will except it if someone doesn't provide me with the actual sample files and implementation guides.

Comment: Here is a link to Safeway's 820 guideline: suppliers.safeway.com/usa/pdf/X12_820_004010.pdf There's a sample file in there, complete with ISA. The 827 might be harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

for specs see: http://www.disa.org/
the x12 specs are not for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase the specifications from http://www.disa.org. There is a cost associated with them, however. It will most likely be < $1000, and you'll get all of the messages. However, you do need to know the *version*, which will be a number like 004010 or 006020.

The specifications do not come with a lot of examples. But examples can be found all over the internet. For example, if you Google `820 004010 example` (the message, the version, and "example"), you get quite a few links, one of which leads you to a nice little sample page like https://www.emedny.org/hipaa/emedny_transactions/820/820_sample_files.aspx and another to http://www.cokeconsolidatededi.com/EDISetups/Forms/CCBCC%20Inbound%20820%20Payments%20004010%20Ex.pdf (those are just the first two that came up for me).